# psftp.exe get files from the server and delete

Tags: batch-file, file-io, ssh, sftp

I'm using `psftp.exe` to download files from the server. Is there an easy way to delete these files once I have downloaded them but leave the new ones that might have appeared on the server when I was downloading to be downloaded next time?

Here's my command line:

```
psftp.exe domain.com -i keys\private.ppk
get *.xml
```

Edit: I want to download the files from a Linux box to a Windows PC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this with `psftp`. You would have to parse its output to find files that were successfully downloaded.

---

Though you can do this easily with WinSCP. Just use [`get -delete *.xml` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get).

Full WinSCP script would be:

```
open sftp://domain.com/ -privatekey=keys\private.ppk -hostkey=...
get -delete *.xml
exit
```

See an [introduction to WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

See also a [guide for converting PSFTP script to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

You can also have [WinSCP GUI generate script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) like this for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer is good. The below is more industrial.

Moving them to a staging area before the download may be prudent.

Generally you would move/rename the files on the server as a starting point. They are going to be deleted anyway so nothing should miss them? nor would you want to fall back over a recent file.
(so restart after this point in the event of a subsequent failure)

Then perform the download.
Then perform the delete.

Answer (score -2):

I would approach the issue differently. Instead of deleting the file from the server, add the downloaded filename to a local table of "Already downloaded files". Then when you scan the FTP again for new files, ignore any that are in that table.

That way the next time you run your download script you only get the new files, but the old files remain on the server.

You could have another script that runs periodically and deletes all files over a certain age.

WINSCP is alright, and Martin (the author) drops in to practically every PuTTy thread to recommend it, but it's a fully GUI-based app and not for me. If you really need everything to be done on the commandline then WINSCP is often not an option.

Comment: WinSCP has GUI, indeed. But it also has scripting. And my answer shows how to use it to solve the problem. So I do not understand what you mean by *"If you really need everything to be done on the commandline then WINSCP is often not an option"*.

Comment: I do admire your dedication to shilling your own software on here Martin but I think it's fine to have alternate solutions as well. WinSCP is good but i've found replacing it with PSFTP.EXE from PuTTY results in transfers completing much quicker, plus the open source bores in my company are much happier using that than something with the word "Win" in the name.

Comment: Sure, psftp works too, I have nothing against it. I just do not understand the *specific part I've quoted*.